# PHP klein router call special controller function

Tags: php, function, controller, router, klein-mvc

I'm implementing the Klein router in php and I have a little problem...
I would like to call a special function from my controller, giving it (or not) $request variable like this :

```
$klein->respond('GET', '/[i:id]?', HomeController::view($request));
```

But I have the error : **Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Expected a callable. Got an uncallable NULL**
So I changed my code to :

```
$klein->respond('GET', '/[i:id]?', new HomeController::view($request));
```

and now the error is this one : **syntax error, unexpected 'view' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'**
Finally I found a solution writting my code like this :

```
$klein->respond('GET', '/[i:id]?', function($request){ HomeController::view($request); });
```

This one is working but I feel I'm missing something... I would like to factorize this, is there any solution?
Thanks you

Comment: I never used Klein: Do you have a Class called *HomeController* with a `public static method view($request) { ... }`?

Comment: Yes I have, I'm sorry, maybe I should ask directly to the Author of the plugin... Because in fact my question is 'It is possible to factorize', i found the way to make it work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$klein->respond('GET', '/[i:id]?', array('HomeController','view'));
```

In the Klein examples, like in your third example, we're passing a closure, or an anonymous function, or a lambda, or whatever else you want to call it.  At any rate, because we're declaring it inline, we have to specify the parameters.

On the other hand, `HomeController::view` has its arguments specified in its own declaration.  If you put the arguments inline, like in your first and second examples, you're actually calling your `view` function on that line.  You want to pass the function to `$klein`, to be called later, which is what my example above should do.

Klein's `respond` function takes what PHP refers to as a callable.  It turns out there's a million ways to specify a callable in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

I was thinking you could do `$klein->respond('GET', '/[i:id]?', HomeController::view);` but that doesn't appear to be correct.  It works in Python, but not PHP.  Oh well.

If you're using PHP 5.4 or later, you can use the short array syntax:

```
$klein->respond('GET', '/[i:id]?', ['HomeController','view']);
```

to make it a little more compact.

Comment: This is it, I was totally looking for it, thanks you a lot!